# Is the natural action of the monoid of endomorphisms is a complete invariant for group?

Tags: gr.group-theory, semigroups-and-monoids

Let $\alpha$ and $\beta$ be actions of semigroups $A$ and $B$ on sets $X$ and $Y$ respectively. Recall that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are called isomorphic if there exists an isomorphism $\phi$  between the semigroups and a bijection  $\psi$ between the sets such that $\forall f \in A, x \in X : \psi (f (x))) = (\phi (f)) (\psi (x))$.

Let $G$ and $H$ be groups. Consider the natural actions of endomorphism monoids $\operatorname{End}(G)$ and $\operatorname{End}(H)$ on $G$ and $H$ respectively. Is it true that if these actions are isomorphic, then $G$ and $H$ are isomorphic?

Comment: I think there are many torsion-free abelian groups $A$ of given cardinal $\alpha$ (countable, or continuum) whose endomorphism ring is reduced to $\mathbf{Z}$ (see the references [at this MathSE answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/93805/35400). I guess it can also be arranged that the maximal locally cyclic subgroups are cyclic . As a $(\mathbf{Z},\times)$-set, $A$ is then just a disjoint copy of $\{0\}$ and $\alpha$ copies of $\mathbf{Z}$ (the maximal cyclic subgroups) with the standard action.

Comment: The question seems interesting for finite groups, though.

Comment: For finite groups: I guess that for large $p$ (say $p\ge 7$) one can find examples among groups of exponent $p$ and order $p^7$ (or $p^8$). Some computer help would be useful. Namely take some known 1-parameter family of 7-dimensional Lie algebras, and take it over $Z/pZ$. Computer can help described the endomorphism semigroup and converge to the right example. Also there are lists of finite $p$-groups and computer can help too (e.g., among groups of order 16, 32, 64, etc).